# What is the maximum possible size of VARCHAR(255)?

Tags: postgresql, drupal, character, byte

On Drupal documentation page (https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/schema-api/data-types/varchar) I read:

> Make sure you are aware of the effects of a multi-byte character set. VARCHAR(255) stores 255 characters, which may be more than 255 bytes.

So I got curious what is the maximum possible size of 255 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 2279](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2279), the highest possible character (code point 0x7FFF FFFF) could be represented by 6 bytes. The highest possible code point you can represent in PostgreSQL is 0x10FFFF, which occupies 4 bytes:

```
SELECT E'\U0010FFFF';

 ?column? 
══════════
 
(1 row)

SELECT E'\U00110000';
ERROR:  invalid Unicode escape value at or near "\U00110000"
LINE 1: SELECT E'\U00110000';
                 ^

SELECT CAST(E'\U0010FFFF' AS bytea);

   bytea    
════════════
 \xf48fbfbf
(1 row)
```

So you are on the safe side if you assume an upper limit of 4 bytes per character.

Comment: Thanks. So is 0x10FFFF an emoji of some kind or what is it?

Comment: No, it is in the "Supplementary Private Use Area-B", so I guess that's a character that you can use for your own private purposes. But you can store it in PostgreSQL.